# MySQL ORDER BY ignored with GROUP BY (Efficient work around?)

Tags: mysql, many-to-one

I feel there is a simple solution to this -- I've looked at other questions on Stack Overflow, but they seem to be inefficient, or perhaps I'm doing them wrong.

Here are simplified versions of tables I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE object_values (
  object_value_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  object_id INT,
  value FLOAT,
  date_time DATETIME,
  INDEX (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE object_relations (
  object_group_id INT,
  object_id INT,
  INDEX (object_group_id, object_id)
);
```

There is a many-to-one relationship -- many object values per one object (150 object values on average per object)

I want to get the last object value (determined by date_time field) for each object_id based on the object_group_id.

Current Query:

```
SELECT a.`object_id`, a.`value` 
FROM `object_values` AS a 
    LEFT JOIN `object_relations` AS b 
        ON ( a.`object_id` = b.`object_id` ) 
WHERE b.`object_group_id` = 105 
ORDER BY a.`date_time` DESC
```

This pulls back all the records -- if I do a GROUP BY a.`object_id` then the ORDER BY gets ignored

I have tried a series of variations -- and I apologize as I know this is a common question, but trying the other solutions hasn't quite worked so far. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Some of the solutions came back with results about 70 seconds later -- this is a large system so needs to be a bit faster.

Comment: I doubt order by is ignored; `GROUP BY` may not be returning the records you want but the final rows will be ordered. Your not returning what your ordering by so how can verify this? I would guess that the whole query is ill-formed and returning wrong / missing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.object_id, a.`value`
FROM object_values a JOIN object_relations b
    ON a.object_id = b.object_id
    JOIN (
    SELECT a.object_id, MAX(a.date_time) MaxTime
    FROM object_relations b JOIN object_values a
        ON a.object_id = b.object_id
    WHERE b.`object_group_id` = 105 
    GROUP BY a.object_id
  ) g ON a.object_id = g.object_id AND a.date_time = g.MaxTime
WHERE b.`object_group_id` = 105 
GROUP BY a.object_id
```

You can omit the final `GROUP BY` if there will never be duplicate `date_time` in a single group.

Comment: I'm interested in your solution -- had to modify it slightly (changed the "g.date_time" in the ON clause to "g.MaxTime"), it pulled back 46 records, it should only pull back 10.

Comment: @kerry Sorry i thought you were grouping by `object_group_id`. See updated answer

Comment: @ The Scrum -- perfect, very fast

Answer (score 1):

Try this version without a group by, using a sub-query to pull the max date for each object:

```
SELECT a.`object_id`, a.`value` 
FROM `object_relations` b 
JOIN `object_values` a 
 ON b.`object_id` = a.`object_id`
 AND b.`object_group_id` = 105
WHERE a.`date_time` = (select MAX(date_time) from object_values where object_id = a.object_id)
```

The left join was unneeded since you specified the group ID in the where clause, so I made the group the main table in the join.  This could be done several ways.  The sub query could also be moved to the join clause if WHERE is just changed to AND.